# Open Source - what if someone commits a crime with my application

Tags: licensing, open-source

I have been recently asked to prepare a network scanner for association that teaches and lectures about security in information technology (mainly pro bono).
I'm thinking of putting it as an *open source* project on GitHub for others to benefit from it and (probably) for mentioned organization, so that others can learn concepts they teach based on it.

***My question is:*** **what happens if such project/application is used for commiting a crime?
Is there any open source license that I can use to prohibit such usage?** 
*AFAIK, scanning ports (or whole networks) is not a crime per se but is a gateway for exploiting potential hosts.*

If there's a topic that covers it already (which I couldn't find I'm afraid), please feel free to let me know and mark it as duplicate.

**Note:**
I'm not asking for a legal advice but for preferred license I could use and open source community approach for such topics in general.

Comment: legal assistance is off-topic per [help/on-topic]

Comment: I'm asking about licensing and open source community approach per se, not for a legal assistance. Similiar questions are widely asked around here from what I've seen. Thanks for pointing out tho.

Comment: "If I want to protect myself from taking responsibility for such actions..." - that reads like asking for legal advice to me

Comment: Alright, edited.

Comment: "What if I build a car and the person who buys it runs someone down with it?"

Comment: If someone wants to use the software for a crime, do you think they are going to care what license it is under?

Comment: They don't care but I do. That's what licensing is for.

Comment: In case of criminal issues, the judge will look at the factual elements.  If the software was made purposely for illegal activities, you might get sued (as the programmer of a famous filesharing site that was shut down recently) and this **whatever you write in your license**. So writing a disclaimer in the license will only show your good will, but will not protect you. The tool that you describe seems however to follow a legitimate purpose. In case of doubt, consult a legal advisor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nearly all of the reasonably well known open-source licenses contain a disclaimer of liability for the result of anything that's done with the software. For example, the [Boost license](http://www.boost.org/users/license.html) includes:

> IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS OR ANYONE DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE BE LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

The [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) (for another example) contains essentially identical wording:

> IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

You could, of course, include a clause specifically saying that the licensee agrees to only use the software in ways that are legal, but it's probably not going to mean much--if somebody's decided to commit a criminal act, violating a mere license agreement isn't likely to change their mind.

In other words, the obvious step would be to use one of the well-known, widely recognized licenses like these that does its best to absolve you of any liability for the results of actions others might take with software you wrote and released.

Comment: I tend to use an MIT license for most of my open source projects, so it should be suitable. Thanks for elaborating on topic!

Comment: But if someone hacks into my computer using your software with this license, then you might still be liable, because _I_ didn't enter any license agreement with you.

Comment: If I would go this way @gnasher729 I could've sue creators of Apache or nginx because someone created malicious webpage upon those webservers. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @mwilczynski: Nonsense. If nobody has sued against Apache, for example, it's not because of the license, it's because Apache is not designed to hack into computers. The OP is writing software that could be used to attack computers or help with an attack. The license gives the author no protection against third parties.

Comment: @gnasher729: but *nothing* you put in a license can really protect you from actions taken by somebody who isn't bound by the license. In theory you could have the license require any licensee to assume liability and defend you if you did get sued, but good luck enforcing that with open source, where you probably don't even know who wrote the malicious code.